# Where can I find HotRod file : startServer.bat (Windows users)

Tags: batch-file, protocols, infinispan

I downloaded infinispan-6.0.0.Final-all.zip.

I need to implement **Infinispan Server**, using **HotRod** protocol, but, I don't find at all the file **startServet.bat** that they mention in their documentation.

Can anybody give me the right link to get it? or the best thing would if somebody give me a small sample of code.

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server has now been separated and it's a different download. Once you've downloaded [it](http://downloads.jboss.org/infinispan/6.0.2.Final/infinispan-server-6.0.2.Final-bin.zip), run it with `/bin/standalone.sh`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It would be better to do an update to the documentation... Because according to the documentation "Getting Started", it is not separated yet.

Comment: Yeah, we've got some updates coming up for Hot Rod 2.0 protocol, so we'll add them there.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [Infinispan Server Guide](http://infinispan.org/docs/6.0.x/infinispan_server_guide/infinispan_server_guide.html).

In the download link, you imagine that ***-all.zip** would include servers as well. But it doesn't.